# will you be able to do a clean install to 8.1 from the windows 8 update download

Tags: windows, installation, windows-8.1

I have windows 8 already so I will be getting the free update to 8.1 when it is released later this month, but I want to do it as a clean install rather than an update. Will the download of the update give me the option of doing a complete clean install or do I need to upgrade from my existing windows 8 OS.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: This can only be answered once the update is released.  The current method allows for an upgrade and a clean install.  If you really want a clean install, it likely will always required, a Windows 8.1 authentication key.

Comment: Updating is going to be faster than fresh install and you might end up resolving the issues that led you to decide on a fresh install

Answer (score 1):

it will download complete windows setup files in C:\$Windows.~BT or C:\WindowsESD

you can copy this to USB drive, mark it active (use google), boot from it and install